# ionic : clear text field on ion-back-button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i am scanning product barcode using BarcodeScanner.

After scanning barcode, product id  is shown in text field and it is sent to another page where i call an api and show product details. Now on product details page I have a back button which takes user back to scanning page.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-back-button default-href=""></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Product Details</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

After coming back to this page product id scanned is still there in the text field,  what I want is to refresh the page after coming back using  back button I tried

```
 ionViewWillEnter() {
  }
```

that did not work .

Can someone please advise me how can i achieve that

Comment: Try using ionViewWillLeave.

Comment: Is your product page is a modal ?

Answer (score 0):

With ionViewDidEnter you can try like this

**.ts file**

```
pid: any = "";

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
 
}

ionViewDidEnter() {
 this.pid = "";
}

getid(){
this.pid = '23232'
}

gotoNext() {
this.navCtrl.push(ContactPage, { id: this.pid });
}
```

**.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
<h2> product id : {{pid}} </h2>
<button ion-button (click)="getid()"> get product id </button>
<button ion-button (click)="gotoNext()"> next </button>
</ion-content>
```

I have created a demo for this , kindly take a look at it

[Demo for the Same](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gnfdyg?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)